# Exploring HSQL database using SQL queries?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I'm using HSQL for the first time. I've previously used MySQL. It appears to lack MySQL commands such as SHOW TABLES. I will still need get information like that occasionally though. This is somewhat similar, but it returns more tables than I care for (not all my own):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES where TABLE_TYPE='TABLE'
```

So for that reason I would like to explore the meta tables being used by HSQL, but I don't know how. Could someone run me through the basics of how to explore an HSQL database to find out information about the overall structure. For example

1. How would I find out the column names of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES?
2. How could I even have found INFORMATION_SCHEMA in the first place?
3. How do I find "siblings" to SYSTEM_TABLES?
4. How to get details about a column, like primary key and such?

etc.

Comment: Why don't you use a SQL (GUI) client which shows all of that?

Comment: Me transitioning to HSQL sparked my interest in knowing how to do this by command line. Sure, if I was just interested in the end result I could do as you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of this information is covered in the HSQLDB Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_standard_views_info_schema

The Standard view equivalent is `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and you can filter out the system views by adding `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'` or a similar condition.

The column details are in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, while primary keys are listed in `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`.